# Why my add-ons viewing on internet explorer "manage add-ons" menu?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, setup-project, add-on

I am writing an add-on for Internet Explorer 11.

I have already added guid variables:

```
 [ComVisible(true), Guid("86524891-49EB-4F46-BAE3-C5545B81A671"), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
```

And already added references to MSHTML and SHDocVw
And already write ComRegister function, unregister function

```
[ComRegisterFunction]
public static void RegisterBHO(Type type)
{
    RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(BHOKEYNAME, true);
    if (registryKey == null)
    {
        registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(BHOKEYNAME);
    }

    string guid = type.GUID.ToString("B");
    RegistryKey ourKey = registryKey.OpenSubKey(guid);
    if (ourKey == null)
    {
        ourKey = registryKey.CreateSubKey(guid);
    }

    ourKey.SetValue("Alright", 1);
    registryKey.Close();
    ourKey.Close();
}

[ComUnregisterFunction]
public static void UnregisterBHO(Type type)
{
    RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(BHOKEYNAME, true);
    string guid = type.GUID.ToString("B");

    if (registryKey != null)
    {
        registryKey.DeleteSubKey(guid, false);
    }
}
```

And I've already  set / get site functions:

```
public int SetSite([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object site)
{
    if (site != null)
    {
        webBrowser = (SHDocVw.WebBrowser)site;
        webBrowser.DocumentComplete += new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(this.OnDocumentComplete);
        webBrowser.BeforeNavigate2 += new DWebBrowserEvents2_BeforeNavigate2EventHandler(this.OnBeforeNavigate2);
        webBrowser.NavigateComplete2 += WebBrowser_NavigateComplete2;
    }
    else
    {
        webBrowser.DocumentComplete -= new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(this.OnDocumentComplete);
        webBrowser.BeforeNavigate2 -= new DWebBrowserEvents2_BeforeNavigate2EventHandler(this.OnBeforeNavigate2);
        webBrowser.NavigateComplete2 -= WebBrowser_NavigateComplete2;
        webBrowser = null;
    }

    return 0;
}

private void WebBrowser_NavigateComplete2(object pDisp, ref object URL)
{
}

public int GetSite(ref Guid guid, out IntPtr ppvSite)
```

{
        IntPtr punk = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(webBrowser);
        int hr = Marshal.QueryInterface(punk, ref guid, out ppvSite);
        Marshal.Release(punk);
        return hr;
    }

Then I added a setup project:

[Setup project propery İmage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACZdw.jpg)

So when I setup the project, I can't see my "add-on" in Internet Explorer. Any suggestions?

Comment: Amended question text for clarity and code formatting

Answer (score 0):

If you believe it's a registration issue then you should show the definition of BHOKEYNAME. It's also unlikely that the Site functions are related to deployment because they are called by the browser when your BHO is correctly hooked up.

It's unclear what other "wiring" you may or may not have put in your setup project. Windows Installer will not just call those register functions. You have to arrange for that to happen somehow - when you're in development mode (and not deployment mode) that's what RegAsm.exe will do, but that is tricky from a setup project.

The other thing that seems to be missing is the COM part. If your Dll needs registering for COM, there appears to be nothing in your setup project that will do any COM registration.

So I believe there are at least two things that need doing:

1. It appears that your Dll needs COM registration, therefore you should go to the properties window for the Dll in the File System view and choose a vsdr COM setting.
2. If you need BHO registry entries creating then why not just use the Registry view in the setup project? All the functionality for creating (and automatically uninstallng) registry entries is in there, and you don't need any code at all to get that done.